# MATLAB differentiation when the derivative of a function is numerically known

Tags: matlab

I want to differentiate the following function wrt in MATLAB:
T(<sup>e(x(t),t)</sup>⁄<sub>p(t)</sub>)

My problem is that I know the derivatives of x numerically (I am inside a kind of odefun).
I want to use diff to make my code generalizeable for high order derivatives,but the derivatives of x are now constant. I would also like all this to be in an anonymous function where I can make the differentiation and substitute accordingly the time and the derivative of x needed,so that I don't have to write multiple functions for every state of my system.

My code is as follows:

```
syms q x star;
qd=symfun(90*pi/180+30*pi/180*cos(q),[q]);
p=symfun(79*pi/180*exp(-1.25*q)+pi/180,[q]);
T=log(-(1+star)/star);
e=symfun(x-qd,[x,q]);
```

and I want to write for example a function in the form

@(t,y)(<sup>d^2</sup>⁄<sub>dt^2</sub> T(<sup>e(x(t),t)</sup>⁄<sub>p(t)</sub>)+<sup>d</sup>⁄<sub>dt</sub> T(<sup>e(x(t),t)</sup>⁄<sub>p(t)</sub>)+T(<sup>e(x(t),t)</sup>⁄<sub>p(t)</sub>))

Comment: I don't understand your code, in particular I struggle to find the above formula in it. From the description however I gather that your problem is that the time derivative of `x` is not a known function. So one thing you could do is to calculate the derivative for many values of `x` and then approximate by a known function (essentially interpolating it). If you approximate the derivative by a low order polynomial then you will be able to calculate its higher order derivatives as well although you probably do not need that as you intend to use diff.

Comment: The formula occurs if you substitute the variable "star" with "e(x(t),t)⁄p(t)".x is not really a function! I only know the values x,x',x'' at a given moment t.

Comment: OK, now I understand, I think. Initially I thought that `e` was Euler number (ie `exp(.)`) while it is a function `e(.)`. I also missed that you know the higher order derivatives of `x` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the implementation details but in general this is one approach that you could take. It involves two steps.

1. in the `T(.)` function replace `x` with `exp(t)` this way when you do the differentiation `exp(t)` always stays there for the higher order derivatives to be taken and the outer functions will be differentiated with respect to `x` at the same time. After you do `diff` you should receive an expression that contains `exp(t)` (not tested so hopefully it is the case). At this point `exp(t)` is your time derivative of `x`. Now you only need to evaluate this expression in `t`. When doing so you need to replace `exp(t)` by the derivative of `x`. I do not know if this can be done, if not then perhaps using `y` instead of `exp(t)` with the constraint `y=exp(t)` would do it but you need to figure the correct implementation out yourself.
2. Here you need to substitute the derivative of `x` at the right `t`. If you do not have the value at the particular point `t` then do what I suggested in the comment. Pre-calculate it beforehand in many points and interpolate in this step.

This approach relies on swapping `x(t)` with `exp(t)` if that does not work then I would do what I suggested in the comment. Approximate `x(t)` by a known function and use that instead of `x` in your code.