# Can I change the formula of a symbolic function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differentiation

I have the following code:

```
syms t x;
e=symfun(x-t,[x,t]);
```

In the problem I want to solve x is a function of t but I only know its value at the given t,so I modeled it here as a variable.I want to differentiate e with respect to time without "losing" x,so that I can then substitute it with x'(t) which is known to me.
In another question of mine here,someone suggested that I write the following:

```
e=symfun(exp(t)-t,[t]);
```

and after the differentiation check if I can substitute exp(t) with the value of x'(t).

Is this possible?Is there any other neater way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure I understand what you're asking (and I didn't understand your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25219699/2278029) either), but here's an attempt.

Since, `x` is a function of time, let's make that explicit by making it what the help and documentation for [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) calls an "abstract" or "arbitrary" symbolic function, i.e., one without a definition. In Matlab R2014b:

```
syms t x(t);
e = symfun(x-t,t)
```

which returns

```
e(t) =

x(t) - t
```

Taking the derivative of the `symfun` function `e` with respect to time:

```
edot = diff(e,t)
```

returns

```
edot(t) =

D(x)(t) - 1
```

the expression for `edot(t)` is a function of the derivative of `x` with respect to time:

```
xdot = diff(x,t)
```

which is the abstract `symfun`:

```
xdot(t) =

D(x)(t)
```

Now, I think you want to be able to substitute a specific value for `xdot` (`xdot_given`) into `e(t)` for `t` at `t_given`. You should be able to do this just using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), e.g., something like this:

```
sums t_given xdot_given;
edot_t_given = subs(edot,{t,xdot},{t_given, xdot_given});
```

You may not need to substitute `t` if the only parts of `edot` that are a function of time are the `xdot` parts.

Comment: Just one more question...
Trying to automate the process of computing derivatives of x,I tried doing the following:
dx=[diff(x,t);diff(x,t,2)];
subs(de1,{dval,q},{[2;2],pi/6})
where de1 has also second order derivatives of x...
But it doesn't work...How can I do that?
To be more precise I don't want to have to write xdot = diff(x,t),xdoubledot=diff(x,t,2) because I might have high order derivatives and many states x1,x2,etc..

Comment: @PavlosTriantafyllou: I don't know what you're asking. I don't see how your `dx` array relates to your `subs` call which doesn't use `dx`. This seems like a separate question. Also, for future reference, saying "But it doesn't work" is not helpful on StackOverflow (or elsewhere). Error messages, expected vs. actual outputs are helpful.

Comment: A million sorry...
There was a typo there...I meant:
`dx=[diff(x,t);diff(x,t,2)]; 
subs(de1,{dx,q},{[2;2],pi/6})`

Comment: Use cell arrays, not arrays. Something like this: `dx={diff(x,t);diff(x,t,2)};` `dxval={2,2};` `subs(de1,{dx{:},q},{dxval{:},pi/6})`.