# Transforming Symbolic Derivatives into Actual Symbols

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

I need to take derivatives in Matlab of a lot of equations w.r.t. generic functions, which will provide me with generic derivatives, of the type:

```
diff(f(x,y),x)
```

or

```
D([1],f(x,y)).
```

What I need is to transform these derivatives into actual symbolic variables, in order to be able to use `solve`, etc. What I am doing now, but which is highly inefficient, is brute force string replacement. Here is a minimal working example of what I am doing:

```
syms x y
f(x,y) = sym('f(x,y)')
jacobian(f)
first_d = jacobian(f)
strrep(char(first_d),'D([1], f)(x, y)','fx')
```

In my real application, I have lots of derivatives to take from lots of equations, so looping such replacements is not the smartest thing to do. Can anybody shed some light into a more efficient solution?

Comment: Some questions. What `version` of Matlab are you using? Are you taking derivatives/Jacobians of abstract symbolic functions, i.e., functions without an explicit definition like your `f(x,y)` (is that what you mean by "generic")? Or are you actually taking derivatives of explicit functions, e.g., `g=x^2+y^2;` or `g(x,y)=x^2+y^2;` (these two `g` functions are very different in terms of how they are manipulated, but they are both explicit)? All symbolic math comes down to string manipulation, but there are way to do this faster sometimes.

Comment: I am using MatLab R2014b 64bit. I am taking derivatives of functions without explicit defintions, which I called generic lacking a better word at the moment. Can you suggest a faster way to the string manipulation or shed some light at a possible path?

Comment: Okay, I'll take a crack at this in the next day or so. In the meantime, you might check out this [closely-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27085362/2278029) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25227675/2278029). The answers are more focused on explaining and solving the basic problem, rather than speed, however. Also, Matlab refers to symbolic functions without explicit definitions as "abstract" or "arbitrary" functions (see `help symfun` or `doc symfun`).

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at those. If you manage someting, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Note: I'm using R2014b. Symbolic Math functionality has changed greatly in recent versions and continues to do so. Users on different versions may need to do slightly different things to achieve the results below, which relies on accessing undocumented functionality.</sub>

First, since this is about performance, it is sufficient to simply declare

```
syms f(x,y)
```

which also defines `x` and `y` as symbolic variables.

As I mention in my comments above, Matlab/MuPAD's symbolic math is all about manipulating strings. Doing this more directly and and adding in you own knowledge of the problem can help speed things up. You want to avoid unnecessary conversions between strings and the `sym`/`symfun` types.

**1.** The first thing to do is investigate how a particular symbolic math function is handling input and output and what lower level private functions it is calling. In the case of your [`jacobian`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html) function example, type `edit jacobian` in your command window to view the code in the Editor. Much of what you see may be confusing, but you should see this line:

```
res = mupadmex('symobj::jacobian',Fsym.s,v.s);
```

This calls the low level `'symobj::jacobian'` function and passes in string versions of the function and variables. To call this yourself, you can do (this also assumes you know your variables are `x` and `y`):

```
syms f(x,y)
first_d = mupadmex('symobj::jacobian',char(f),char([x,y]))
```

This returns `[ diff(f(x, y), x), diff(f(x, y), y)]`. The undocumented `mupadmex` function is a direct way of calling MuPAD function from within Matlab – [there are others](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html), which are documented.

**2.** You'll notice that that the `first_d` output above is `symfun` class. We actually don't want want the output to be converted back to a symbolic function. To avoid this, we can pass an addition argument to `mupadmex`:

```
syms f(x,y)
first_d = mupadmex('symobj::jacobian',char(f),char([x,y]),0)
```

with now returns the string `matrix([[diff(f(x, y), x), diff(f(x, y), y)]])`. (I only know this trick of adding the additional `0` argument from having browsed through a lot of Symbolic Math toolbox code.)

**3.** From this string, we can now find and replace various patterns for partial derivatives with simple variables. The [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) function that you're using is generally a good choice for this. It is much faster than [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html). However, if you have a large number of different, but similar, patterns to replace, you might do a performance comparison between the two. That would probably be the subject of a separate question.

I'm not sure what your overall goal is or the full extent of your problem, but here is my final code for your example:

```
syms f(x,y)
first_d = mupadmex('symobj::jacobian',char(f),char([x,y]),0)
first_d = strrep(first_d(9:end-2),'diff(f(x, y), x)','fx');
first_d = sym(strrep(first_d,'diff(f(x, y), y)','fy'));
```

This returns the symbolic vector `[ fx, fy]`. If you want a `symfun`, you'll need to modify the last line slightly. In some simple testing, this basic example is about 10% faster than calling `jacobian` and converting the result back to a string. If you directly specify the inputs as strings instead of allocating a symbolic function, the result is about 30% faster then your original:

```
first_d = mupadmex('symobj::jacobian','f(x,y)','[x,y]',0)
first_d = strrep(first_d(9:end-2),'diff(f(x, y), x)','fx');
first_d = sym(strrep(first_d,'diff(f(x, y), y)','fy'));
```

Using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086016/2278029), while convenient, is the slowest approach. Converting back and forth to and from strings is costly.